# How to permanently enable manual eject button on my optical (CD/DVD) drive under Ubuntu Studio 22.04?

Tags: dvd, cd-drive, eject

It drove me nuts that the eject button on my optical drive stopped working after I installed Ubuntu Studio 22.04. I find it counter intuitive and a PITA.  My PC is a tower PC under my desk, well out  of the way of any accidental button push. As it stands, I have to open a terminal window to open the drive to put in a disk, because the drive doesn't appear in Krusader (or anywhere else in the GUI) until there is something in it. I have used

```
eject -i
```

to restore operation of the eject button, but this appears to be only temporary.  How can I *permanently* restore what I consider to be normal operation of the eject button?

Comment: Is there some site or reference I can look at that says that this is the default?

Comment: You could try installing ubuntu and installing the studio desktop on it...

Comment: @David, I couldn't find one; I was only reporting my experience.

Comment: @Rishon_JR, Thanks for the suggestion, but Id rather endure the inconvenience of an occasional "eject" command than the inconvenience of a complete OS reinstallation. ;-)